# A short tutorial on how a linux distro is organized and supposed to work

Tags: linux, distributions

I need a tutorial , preferably with pics/diagrams to get oriented to how a typical Linux distro. is organized and  used (including the basic software installation work flow). It shouldn't be a 500 pages book. A concise 20-30 pages tutorial is what I am looking for , so that I read it over the weekend and just dive into Ubuntu/Fedora etc and figure my way around on my own.

Comment: Someone just asked a related question, and the links in the answers might be enough for a start: [this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7899/how-do-i-know-where-to-put-things-in-linux) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the [Ultimate Linux Newbie Guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owdEDcmF1SI) videos or read the [Linux.org beginner guide](http://www.linux.org/docs/beginner/install.html)

But to be honest, if you are going for something like Ubuntu you will find it very easy, and if you don't, there is a stack of info over on [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com), including [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/17702/7163) which should have what you'll need.