# Sourcing common scripts from larger scripts in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have accumulated a fair amout of shell scripts that help me configure/administrate my computers, and I'd like to put some order in what's becoming a mess.

In many of them I define utility functions like the following two

```bsh
error() {
  printf '\e[4;5;31m%-s\e[m\n' "$@" >&2
}
warning() {
  printf '\e[4;5;33m%-s\e[m\n' "$@" >&2
}
```

What I'd like to do is put these and other common functions each in their own `.sh` file, maybe organizing them in a directory hierarchy, so that other bash scripts can "include" the ones they need before doing anything else.

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201768/storing-shell-scripts) is related, but I don't want those "common" functions to be available in the shell, I just want them to be available to the script that choose to use them, that's why I said those scripts should "include" these functions.

What are the recommended ways of "including" such common functions?

At the moment, I'm experimenting on something like this:

```bsh
# this is myscript.sh residing in /home/enrico/path/to/
# error.sh only has the error() function as defined above, so I have to use echo to print the error message if I don't find it
source "$(dirname "$0")/commons/error.sh" || { echo "error.sh not found" >&2 && exit 1; }
# error() is available now
source "$(dirname "$0")/commons/warning.sh" || { error "warning.sh not found" && exit 1; }
# waringin() is available too
# ...
command_that_can_fail || error "failed because of bla and bla"
condition_to_be_concerned_about || warning "hey, there's something you should worry about"
```

I have `source`d those two scripts prepending `"$(dirname "$0")/` (to the position of those two files relative to `myscript.sh`) in order to be able to run `myscript.sh` from any directory, e.g. `/home/enrico/path/to/myscript.sh`. Is this technique just fine? Are there any drawbacks?

One drawback I can think of, is that I cannot use `shellcheck`'s `source` directives with that line.